# How To Display Label In Product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have referred this below link.

> [Magento- Custom Product labels in category view pages](http://www.woolleydesign.net/2013/07/magento-shop-product-labels-in-category-view-pages/)

I Have

1. created 1 static block name : new_sale
2. Created 1 Attribute : new_sale

My list.phtml Code--

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<div class="middle-left">
<?php 
$collections = Mage::getModel('simplebanner/simplebanner')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
foreach($collections as $collection) { 
echo '<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'/'.$collection->getImage().'" height="50" width="50" >'; 
}
?>
</div>
```

How Would I Create My list.phtml ?
As Per I Give Link Has A list.phtml
But I Wan't To Display My Image.

Comment: Tell me above code output .

Comment: As per i give a link, link has a one file list.phtml. it has function  <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
i write this all code in my list.phtml it give me a fetal error

Comment: where you get fatal error??

Comment: At The Front End Product listing Page

Comment: Pls, If U See I Give A Link, Link Has A list.phtml Code,

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\xampp2\htdocs\magento1.9\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 37

Comment: You can resolve the error by replacing code in your phtml file like this>
Replace $_productCollection->count() with count($_productCollection);

Comment: I Will Replace This Code, But Still Error are Same To Same..